# String parsing having Special characters

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have a String in this form:

```
String buf = "[[[name11,name12]][[name21,name22]][[name31,name32]]]";
```

How can I retrieve all the names?

When i retreive data from database i recive it in this form.

Looking for Java Solution.

Thanks

Comment: How come you need to parse a string like that? It looks like some sort of `toString()` method from a multi-dimensional array, in which case I'd suggest working on that instead of its string-representation. You might also want to mention in what programming language you're working.

Comment: I see you added that it comes from a DB. Well, I won't suggest a *hacky* `String.split(...)` method (I'm sure someone will in a few minutes...) but I suggest to store that information properly in the DB instead of hacking your way around it. Let's say someone suggest a `split(...)` solution, what do you think happens when one of your names contains a `[`, `]` or `,` literal?

Comment: The name does not contain any special character it just a letter or number. So it does not matter even if someone use String.split("\\\[") or something else.

Comment: Well, okay. Then have a look at the `Scanner` class or use `String.split(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trick should do it:

```
String csv = buf.replace("[[[","").replace("]]]","").replace("]][[",",");
String[] names = csv.split(",");
```

It removes the leading and trailing brackets and replaces the inner brackets with a comma. Now you can split the input around `,` and have an array with the names only.

Comment: String csv = buf.replace("[","").replace("]","") // simpler?

Comment: String[] names = buf.split("[,[\\\]]+"); // even simpler but not sure about the escaping?

Comment: @Tom, no, `buf.replace("[","").replace("]","")` won't work: it "glues" `name12` and `name21` together (and the other names as well).

Comment: @Bart: true; // should have thought of that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class in Java to parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you always have pairs of names?  Is it possible to have [[name2,]]?

If the names always come in pairs then Andreas_D response is a simple straight forward answer.  If one of the names may be missing then you need to add a couple of replace() calls in front to look for these and put dummy values in.  Specifically "[," with "[dummyFirst," and ",]" with ",dummyLast]".  You would then have to process these dummy values according to whatever rules are appropriate for your context.